# Atomikos Hibernate 4.3.7 Causes Multiple Issues

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, atomikos

I have implemented a Spring project that uses Atomikos and Hibernate 3. Recently, I upgraded from Hibernate 3.6.10 to Hibernate 4.3.7 and I seem to get multiple issues. One of them being:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/atomikos/icatch/jta/hibernate3/TransactionManagerLookup
```

I also done the following:

1) Added:
    "hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", com.example.transactionmanager.hibernate4only.AtomikosJtaPlatform // for Hibernate 4 only
    "hibernate.transaction.factory_class", CMTTransactionFactory; // for Hibernate 4 only

2) Removed:
    hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", TransactionManagerLookup // for Hibernate 3

3) Removed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
    <artifactId>transactions-hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This application is to be run as a standalone application. The project is located here: https://github.com/rajivj2/example2/

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong? NotificationRouterIT.java contains the test where the problem is. This works perfectly when using Hibernate 3.